# When does the day start for League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

How does the 'First Win of the Day' IP bonus timer work?  Does it reset at some specific time each day?

Does the IP bonus gained vary depending on the game type; PvP vs. beginner bots vs. intermediate bots?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It resets 22 hours after you complete your previous win of the day. It is always 150 bonus IP. Custom games do not count toward the WOTD.

Comment: Are you sure about custom games? They used to. I know that Co-Oop vs. AI do as well.

Comment: See: [Do you lose some of the "first win of the day" IP boost by playing in Beginner AI games?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26333/26336#26336) for the custom games.

Comment: IIRC it's been changed to 20 hours.