# Do you lose some of the "first win of the day" IP boost by playing in Beginner AI games?

Tags: league-of-legends

At higher levels in League of Legends, your IP and XP earned from AI games gets penalized.  Does this impact the "First Win of the Day" bonus though?  Some days I just want to mindlessly blast through a game and get the +150.

Comment: I'm very confident that the 150 IP is the same regardless of which mode you get your first win of the day in, but I don't have a source.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the +150 bonus-of-the-day is not impacted by playing an AI game or a Custom Game instead of a PvP game. You need only make sure that you win the game, and you'll earn an un-changed +150 IP on top of however much (reduced) XP/IP you get normally.

It's actually not uncommon that some players will specifically do a relatively quick AI match just to secure that win, especially if you're having a bad day on the PvP end.

Comment: My brother is the perfect anecdotal example, for this is exactly what he does.